# ios socket outputstream bytes

Tags: android, ios, sockets, nsoutputstream

I find these code on the [website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server),and rewrite it into my current code
,I can successfully connect to the server side.But I still had some problems:

**outputStream:**

According to the code on the website, I can normally send string

```
- (IBAction)sendCmd:(id)sender
{
    NSString *response  = @"Hello World!";
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

But I want to send bytes,(e.g 0x80,0x10,0x20...etc.)
Android syntax is:

```
         byte[] buf=new byte[10];
                buf[0]=(byte) 0x80;  
                buf[1]=(byte) 0x10; 
                buf[2]=(byte) 0x20;
```

But replaced ios,I don't know how to do?
Give me some advice or website,grateful.

Comment: What is the problem? Use an OutputStream too and its write() method.

Comment: `-[outputStream write: maxLength:]` takes bytes. That's why you have to do the whole encoding to `NSData` and calling `[data bytes]` and `[data length]` thing when you have a string. If you already have bytes, just send them.

Comment: I'm sorry I may have made a fatal mistake ...what I wanna show is to convey a HEX,

Comment: I have no idea what "convey a HEX" means. If you mean you want to send the string "0x80,0x10,0x12" or "801012" or something like that, rather than what your Android code sends, then that's fine—it's just a string, which you can send the same as any other string (using your original code). Again, to make this clear: your Android code does _not_ send hex, it just sends the bytes as bytes.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the original version. If you want to ask a new question, after having gotten an answer to your original question, just create a new question. (You can paste links between the two questions—click the "share" button to get a nice link—if you need to.) Otherwise, your question and any existing answers will never be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Very grateful, so a tremendous amount of explained to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "I have bytes", that presumably means either:

- You have an `NSData` or similar type holding the bytes. You can see how to get the bytes and length for that from your existing example—just skip the part where you encode the `NSString` to an `NSData`, because you already have an `NSData`.
- You have a raw C buffer (via a `void *` or `char *` or `unsigned char *` or similar) and a length. That's exactly what [`-[NSOutputStream write: maxLength:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutputStream/write:maxLength:) *wants* from you; where your example passes `[data bytes]` and `[data length]`, just pass your pointer (possibly with a cast) and length values.

For example:

```
const char msg[] = "\x80\x10\x20";
const NSUInteger msglen = sizeof(msg) / sizeof(*msg);
[outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)msg maxLength:msglen];
```

---

If you really want an exact ObjC equivalent of your Android code for some bizarre reason, it would look something like this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:10];
uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t *)[data mutableBytes];
buf[0]=(uint8_t)0x80;
buf[1]=(uint8_t)0x10;
buf[2]=(uint8_t)0x20;
[outputStream write:buf maxLength:3]; // or is that 10?
```

I'm not sure why you're creating a 10-byte buffer and only filling in 3 bytes, but `+dataWithLength` does the same thing as Android Java and leaves the other 7 slots filled with 0's, if that's what you want.

(You can also just use [`calloc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/calloc.3.html) and skip all the ObjC stuff if you want, but then you have to deal with checking for `NULL`, calling `free` at the end even if there was an error somewhere, etc., because C isn't Java…)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I still need to solve some problems

Comment: @ShaneJhan: OK, then go solve them, and if you have a new question while doing so, come back to StackOverflow and post a new question. Don't try to edit this question into a new question.